# gdb C++ how to enable pretty-printer in a command list?

Tags: c++, gdb, cygwin

I have a break point like this:

```
b kuk.cpp:1803 if (v==644)
commands
p m_d.m_state[644]
end
```

I have noticed that the registered pretty-printers inside the command list are only:

```
global pretty-printers:
builtin
   mpx_bound128
```

Outside the command list I have:

```
(gdb) info pretty-printer
global pretty-printers:
  builtin
    mpx_bound128
  objfile /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll pretty-printers:
  libstdc++-v6
    __gnu_cxx::_Slist_iterator
    __gnu_cxx::__7::_Slist_iterator
    __gnu_cxx::__7::__normal_iterator
    __gnu_cxx::__7::slist
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator
    __gnu_cxx::slist
    __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator
    std::_Deque_const_iterator
    std::_Deque_iterator
    std::_List_const_iterator
    std::_List_iterator
 ...
 ...
```

How do I enable all these pretty-printers in my command list?

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty_002dPrinter-Commands.html) says for enabling the following command can be used:

```
enable pretty-printer [object-regexp [name-regexp]]
```

but I am not sure you can enable some of them if it is not listed by `info` command